# Ajax call does not work at first, but successful call afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm working on Cordova hybrid mobile app. I'm calling an API to load data into my variables and process it. Below is the problem.

First, I call the API using ajax. After ajax call, I check if jsonString is empty and if it is, I reload the page to run the ajax call again.

```
$.ajax({
            url: GetConfigUrl // working URL,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                token: '123456'
            },
            cache: false,
            datatype: 'json',
            contenttype: "application/json",               
            success: function (data, response, xhr) {
              debugger
              jsonString = data.Value;
            },
            error: function (data) {
              // do nothing
            )
       });

        if (jsonString == '') {
           // Display popup to ask user the reload the page
        }

        return true;
```

I have a debugger in place in the success call function, but it does not hit and directly go to check if jsonString is empty, which is empty because it does not call the ajax to load data and proceed to display popup to ask user to reload the page.

After hitting the page reload, the debugger in the success call is being hit and able to retrieve the value. Thus the jsonString is not empty and able to proceed.

I check the Network tab in the console, it shows the below result:
[image]

It seems that the first call was made but always remain pending. The second call is the success one and return the correct value. So the jsonString checking is passed.

This issue happen all the time where the first ajax call is not success and in pending but all subsequent calls are successful.

So what could be wrong here? How do I ensure that the first ajax call will be made successfully and return the data all the time?

Answer (score 3):

Ajax is executed asynchronous place your logic in the success function for it to get executed when the ajax call completes

```
$.ajax({
            url: GetConfigUrl // working URL,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                token: '123456'
            },
            cache: false,
            datatype: 'json',
            contenttype: "application/json",               
            success: function (data, response, xhr) {
              debugger
              jsonString = data.Value;
               if (jsonString == '') {
                 // Display popup to ask user the reload the page
               }

            },
            error: function (data) {
              // do nothing
            )
       });


        return true;
```